# Error on car's license plate regex validation

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'm running the following test to validate a car's license plate. What am I doing wrong?

testInvalid return **error**

testValid return **success**

```
@Test
fun testInvalid() {
 val value = "ABC12345"
 val pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}")
 val matcher = pattern.matcher(value)

 val found = matcher.find()

 System.out.print("$value is valid: $found")
 Assert.assertFalse(found)
}

@Test
fun testValid() {
 val value = "ABC1234"
 val pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}")
 val matcher = pattern.matcher(value)

 val found = matcher.find()

 System.out.print("$value is valid: $found")
 Assert.assertTrue(found)
}
```

Comment: Use `matcher.matches()` instead of `matcher.find()` if you want the entire string to be matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the $ character at the end of regEx to indicate the end:

```
@Test
fun testInvalid() {
    val value = "ABC12345"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$")
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(value)

    val found = matcher.find()

    System.out.print("$value is valid: $found")
    Assert.assertFalse(found)
}
@Test
fun testValid() {
    val value = "ABC1234"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$")
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(value)

    val found = matcher.find()

    System.out.print("$value is valid: $found")
    Assert.assertTrue(found)
}
```

Comment: to indicate the end of the regex

Comment: You probably also want to add a `^` at the beginning of the regex